# How can i add an "Action Button" to an BottomTabNavigator with React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm currently working on a Navigation for my new App in React Native. The problem is that im not sure how to implement an "Action Button" like this (https://github.com/geremih/react-native-circular-action-menu) into the React Native Navigation Libary (https://reactnavigation.org/) to get a simular result like that:
https://ibb.co/HF51XhK

Maybe you already have done something similar like this.
Thanks

Comment: should the plus go straight to a new screen?

Comment: I think you can pass the  navigation prop to the component and just call navigation.navigate('ScreenName')

Comment: No the Action Button should be on the navigation bar on the bottom!